# TypeScript promise throws a compile time error but not a run time error

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have this code:

```
async function fetchApi(): Promise<IStoreApi | null> {
    try {
        return await (await fetch("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDcpslXnm?indent=2")).json();
    }
    catch(e: any) {
        return null;
    }
}

console.log(fetchApi);
```

It shows no errors when linting, but when compiling, I get this following error:

```
index.ts(23,28): error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
index.ts(27,14): error TS1196: Catch clause variable cannot have a type annotation.
```

I've tried Googling the error with some tips suggesting I should change my `tsconfig.json` file, but that didn't help.
Also, I find it wierd that I don't get a run time error but I do get a compile time error.

This is my `tsconfig` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom",
            "es2015.promise"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @DenisFrezzato, added it to the question.

Comment: You tsconfig looks alright. Seems like your `tsc` didn’t pick up the correct `tsconfig.json`. Might also need your file structure and the shell command that you use to run the `tsc` tool

Comment: I'm using `tsc-watch`, which, I'm assuming, does the same thing